# Missing Magic Link for Stack Overflow in Portuguese

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, localization, magic-links

Looks like it got lost in translation/development. I've tried

```
[pt.se]
[pt.so]
[portugues.se]
```

but none renders into a [Magic Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in the Comments box.

I've opened [a pt.Meta question](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009/qual-o-link-abreviado-pro-stack-overflow-em-portugues), but, as this is a network wide issue, I think posting here is the proper action to get the issue solved.

Also, given the future [Russian, Turkish and Spanish](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13328/beta-launching-time) implementations, I think this report/request/support question will prevent the same thing from happening when they launch.

Comment: [pt.se] - [pt.so] - [portugues.se] - [portugues.so] - [portuguese.se] - [portuguese.so]

Comment: +1. IMO, `[pt.so]` would be the "natural" choice.

Comment: I could go with `[ptso]` and `[pt-so]` as well. Speaking of which, have you tried these?

Comment: As I understand it, the normal pattern is `[site-name.se]`. But using `[*.so]` would make sense, as those sites are working as a SO localized versions. @JanDvorak, no, those doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added a `[pt.so]` magic link.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.4.10.1539, meta rev 2014.4.10.2153)