# The effect of the MSO/MSE split on Google searches

Tags: support, google, mso-mse-split

It just came to me - I mainly use Google search to search on Meta (what can I say, Google does what it does really well).

Now I know Google caches most stuff, and obviously can't know about a site (or page) straight away when it pops up, unless told about it ... or perhaps if it finds a link somewhere.

So, is there someone on the SE team that knows enough on the topic to calm my doubts regarding Google Meta SE searches when this whole [MSO/MSE split thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014) is over?

I know, or assume, I will now have to search with `site:meta.stackexchange.com`. But will the questions actually be properly indexed on `meta.stackexchange.com` by the time we start using it? Or will every current question on `meta.stackoverflow.com` be replaced by a redirect link to the `meta.stackexchange.com` question? Or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, everything will be redirected, so having the old URLs on Google isn't too bad.

If `301 Moved Permanently` redirects are used, Google will pick it up and realize the switch happened.

Comment: In theory, yes. But how do you actually know that SO will make 301 redirects from each entry they move?

Comment: @davidkonrad They did say that they're making redirects. It makes sense to use 301 redirects, and they're pretty smart.

Comment: If worst comes to worst, Google stops indexing the MSO 404 pages, and starts crawling MSE, which, given the number of pages, might take a while.

Comment: @Manishearth, I agree with the latter, but havent seen that redirect-promise. Can you share a link? They have promised to migrate, not to migrate the links, as I understand.

Comment: @davidkonrad http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014#comment750841_228901

Comment: @davidkonrad [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange/124018#comment331279_124018)

Comment: @Manishearth, thank you - this seems to proof your assumption. And glad you are right.