# What's going to be done about the 301 redirect from MSE to MSO?

Tags: support, mso-mse-split

Currently, there's a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect from MSE to MSO. Now it turns out that the move isn't so permanent.

Indexers expect this redirect to stay put. Will this affect the googleability of the site? I doubt it, but it seems a bit iffy.

Comment: Do we really *need* metas to be Googleable? They're probably not drawing in huge amounts of traffic.

Comment: @Undo [Some people use it, apparently.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229730/the-effect-of-the-mso-mse-split-on-google-searches) On the other hand, it's [kind of a weird workflow.](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: I use google to search MSO.

Comment: I imagine the devs know how to use Webmaster Tools such to tell Google to crawl the site again.