# The site still thinks it's attached to Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, help-center, mso-mse-split

When clicking help, you get this:

[image]

First, it shouldn't have a button to return to the main site, as this site isn't attached to any other site. Second, *What's Meta*'s wording should be changed, because again, there is no main site.

Comment: [They're not done yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build:

[image]

Comment: Mm.... 2014.4.17.2173 build and still there :(

Comment: @Braiam That's the current build. We haven't built the latest round of changes out to the network yet.

Comment: rev 2014.4.17.2174 and fixed :) (Just thought I'd leave a timestamp for for posterity.)