# Should we flag questions on mSE that are strictly about SO?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, meta, mso-mse-split

Yay, we finally split mSO and mSE. However, in browsing the new mSE I'm noticing questions that are strictly about Stack Overflow.

I'm tempted to flag these for migration to the new Meta Stack Overflow, but I wanted to ask first. Do we flag questions that are about SO to request migration?

Comment: There's some info here about the current status of the migratings: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250005/2474859 Not sure it's a full answer, but seems to indicate a big "Not Yet" at least.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, don't flag them. You'll be up all night. And then I'll decline all your flags and we'll both be sad.

If someone asks a *new* question *and* it's specific to Stack Overflow - by which I mean, specific to a community of professional and enthusiast programmers, not "something that happens to apply to Stack Overflow" - then you can flag *that*. Or just leave a comment suggesting that they might be better off asking *over yonder*. But don't try to flush the archives unless your name is Hercules and you happen to have a river handy.

Comment: Lies, the tears of declined flaggers sustain you. But I'll give you credit for foregoing your tearlust in favour of saving him some trouble.

Comment: See also: [Sisyphus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus).

Comment: [It *could* also work if you're Bruce Almighty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyWwEm-rKUY).

Comment: @AnnaLear Also [The Myth of Sisyphus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus)

Comment: @Shog9 feels _sad_ after declining flags.  I'm touched.

Comment: I know this is flogging a dead donkey, but from reading Tim's comments, I don't think the size of the task is the real issue here. There are lots of questions which could have been migrated by tag. Ho hum... MSE gets to be the dustbin.

Comment: Longer discussion of that [in this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014/229487#229487), @Benjol

Comment: I was rather under the impression that "split" meant "split". That is, that the questions about SO would go to MSO while all other questions would go to MSE. But so far, all the questions have gone to MSE and all the statuses say "split is complete". Did I misinterpret something?

Comment: @MrLister This is what should have happened, but not what is being done. MSO starts with a clean slate (if you had a pending request, you're supposed to make it again). MSE gets saddled with all the history. “[This move is intended primarily for the benefit of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014/229487#comment751131_228903)”. (Not that keeping SO-related pending issues and history out of MSO helps SO any.)

Comment: Were you around for the MSO/MSU or MSO/MSF splits, @MrLister? Anyway, there's a blog post up now.

Comment: Is the recommended action then "don't do anything with them"? Can that be added to the answer if so (to make this a nice reference post)? "Don't flag them" is a bit too specific. Or should I post another question about what exactly we should do with them. This conflicts with [Tim advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250976/migrations-are-now-in-progress) - that we should flag *some* of them (although, as per [my comment there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250976/migrations-are-now-in-progress#comment2433_250976), I didn't quite follow the prerequisites for flagging).

Comment: Post a less specific question if you want a more general answer, @Dukeling.

Comment: Fair enough, but what should I do regarding the 2 'official' posts giving seemingly conflicting advice?

Comment: Ask a question to resolve it, @duk