# Stack Overflow meta migration - historical questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, per-site-meta, mso-mse-split

Since the split between Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow, my questions were all migrated to the new Meta Stack Exchange site.

However I remarks there is a tag [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) for those specific questions.

I can understand it was done like this for the migration, but should they not be moved back to the dedicated site Meta Stack Overflow?

I am particularly talking about retag requests, which I guess should be on the dedicated meta.XX for XX site as the tags are different and specific for each sites.

Comment: Irony: This question is also tagged with stackoverflow.

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229785/should-we-flag-questions-on-mse-that-are-strictly-about-so

Comment: Note: your posts were not migrated to MSE. The site was  *renamed*. Your posts stayed in the same place all along.

Comment: Above all else, EXP matters more than having questions in the right place

Comment: @random Evan Carroll for moderator on MSE!

Comment: @random what is EXP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're unresolved *and relatively recent*, which is a hallmark for something that is likely to still be *relevant* - you can flag them for us to review and possibly migrate. I'm *not* going to migrate something if I know that doing so is going to cause one or more users to lose privileges. There are going to be cases where it might just be better to ask anew on MSO while voting to close them here using [the new off-topic custom reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230130/new-custom-close-reason-specific-only-to-a-certain-site) - which will allow them to be deleted over time - effectively migrating the *discussion* without the rep loss side effects.

It's expected that we're going to have a bit of a mess for at least the next few weeks, but don't worry too much about it - those that regularly participate here know what's going on and that we're actively working on a cleanup. It's fine if you want to help in that effort, just don't lose track of the primary purpose of this new place in an effort to get everything organized :)

Comment: So for clarity, if we come across an old question that specifically only applies to Stack Overflow, what should be done?

Answer (score 3):

One of the things they did with the migration was try to preserve people's rep and privilege *here* and only migrate things that were still open issues to the new MSO.

So if your questions were resolved, they wouldn't have been migrated.

If they are still unresolved flag them and the com team can look and see if they need to be migrated over.