# Two and three digit comment vote counts extend beyond comment

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, design, comment-voting

Comments that have three digit votes or two digit votes extend beyond the left side of the comment.

[image]
[image]

Whilst this is visible without hovering over the comment due to the end of the separating line, it is especially noticeable when the comment is hovered over, as above.

<sup>Safari 7.0.3 on OS X 10.9.2

[Link to post above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/222623)</sup>

Comment: No repro (Firefox 28 on Win 7).

Comment: It would help if you could link to the post so that people can see the comment and post your browser and OS. I've been having a fair few problems on Chrome on Win 7 at the moment for instance, but it doesn't seem to be affecting many people.

Comment: No repro here, either (Chrome 34, Windows 7).

Comment: You didn't, by any chance, happen to be using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) when you noticed this behavior?  That's a known side effect of the styling fix I included for [this bug](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1987): the fix makes the comment table left column width constant, causing long vote counts to overflow to the left. With the current SE comment HTML, there's not a lot that I can do about it; increasing the fixed left column width would help here, but would make it look worse for single-digit vote counts.

Comment: @Ilmari I honestly can't remember—it was quite a while ago. I just installed it now to test and it seems fine, but you've made changes to it since April :) I disable userscripts/etc when making bug reports, though maybe I forgot about SOUP at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – not quite sure when, but it has been fixed.

[image]

Comment: The SOUP feature that sometimes triggered this issue has also been rewritten as of v1.22, and should no longer cause this effect.