# Why is Meta.SE on my profile?

Tags: discussion, support, network-profile

Meta.SE is treated like any other parent site in the network. Consequently, it is displayed on the profile. This is bad because it's not a field of expertise one wants to show on profile.

Why did SE team choose to do it?

Comment: Until april 2014 the situation was different as can be read [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What's bad? It's telling people you care about the network you contribute to!

Anyway, if you don't want it to be shown, hide it by going to your profile > Profile tab > Communities section > Edit list and hide it.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

> This is bad because it's not a field of expertise one wants to show on profile

I beg to differ. I am proud to contribute so much on Meta Stack Exchange and it means I do something for the good of the whole network of sites.

I don't think the team chose to show it, more likely they saw no reason to hide/remove it and I totally agree with that.

Last two bits:

1. Is this a Q&A site?
2. Are the posts follow the overall Stack Exchange quality standards?

Yes to both means it's a valid part of Stack Exchange. :)

Comment: Okay. Then, why aren't site specific Meta treated that way?

Comment: Because they don't stand on their own, being just child-meta of a main site.

Answer (score 11):

> ...it's not a field of expertise one wants to show on profile.

Well, this particular field of expertise is the reason why many people around the globe were able to share their different fields of expertise in a very elegant way and direct to the point. That particular field of expertise made SE one of the most trusted sites when it comes to seeking knowledge. So, I would be proud to have a few extra K rep added to my Meta.SE to show in my profile.

Comment: here, another 0.01K rep ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the generosity :D

Answer (score 4):

Participation most certainly does reflect relevant expertise, and as I near an important reputation boundary here I am not embarrassed but rather *happy* to have this site show in my network profile.  Participation here calls for knowledge of [user-oriented design](http://ux.stackexchange.com), [community-building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/), [SQL and the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), [software design](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) (understanding what's practical and consistent with the existing platform, as well as scaling), [web applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), and maybe even the odd bit of [philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com).  While I'm happy to also participate on some of those other sites, only on meta sites (and most especially Meta.SE) do they all come together as we work together on the platform we all depend on.