# My contribution has disappeared - bug?

Tags: support, reputation, mso-mse-split, contribution

I had contributed to a topic and my reputation under Meta shows as:

> Reputation (1)

but there is no record of what I contributed. Clicked on everything possible, but I cannot find it.  Is this a bug?

It gets weirder...
Apparently I have a login for Stack Overflow (reputation 149) and for Meta Stack Exchange (reputation 19... now), but not for Stack Exchange and not for Meta Stack Overflow if there is such a thing.

How did this happen?  One clue might be that I had different email addresses in the two accounts - I have since changed the MSE email address to match SO, but I think (could be wrong) that this is irrelevant.  When the two services split, I must have lost MSO and SE... Somehow..

Comment: Do you remember what the contribution was about or what question you posted it on?

Comment: No I don't remember.  I just remember it was a meta description for a tag.

Comment: When (approx) did you contribute and can you be more precise about what you did? 1 rep is the minimum, you get that when you create an account and can't go below that.

Comment: @Chiwda do you remember how long ago it was?  If it was more than a year ago, it could have been migrated to Meta.Stackoverflow when MSO and MSE split (although you don't have any contributions on MSO either0

Comment: It was definitely over a year ago.  Please note this is important only if it is a bug.  My (1) reputation point is trivial.  So, I am looking to find out if anyone else has reported anything similar. And it was StackOverflow

Comment: There is no relation between your rep here and your rep on Stack Overflow. If you contributed something at some point on SO or SO's meta, it will not influence your rep here. As for something posted 1 year ago on a meta site... well stuff gets deleted on metas.

Comment: Stuff you post on Meta doesn't change your reputation... Is that what you're confused about?

Comment: There is no reputation in http://stackexchange.com/ if that's what you mean, but you do have a [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/966067/chiwda). Nothing weird.

Comment: Please read the question and the answers also.  I am not confused about the reputation. It's about having lost my contribution and later I have discovered that I don't even have a login in two places (SE and MSO) after the split.

Answer (score 6):

I think we should clear things out a little bit. It might help you to diagnose the problem.

I think you are talking about MSE (Meta Stack *Exchange*), not MSO (Meta Stack *Overflow*). Why is that? You can't participate in meta [if you haven't got at least 5 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta), so a reputation of 1 doesn't seem to make sense.

That said, your reputation on the governing Meta, MSE, isn't related to your reputation on other sites, including SO or MSO (your reputation on MSO is the same as on SO itself).

If you have participated, there isn't any proof of it we can see as normal users. This can have a number of reasons:

- You posted before the [MSO/MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/245360). Your post has been migrated to MSO. You have lost your reputation on this site due to that. (That seems unlikely in your case since there aren't any visible posts from you on MSO, or any badges indicating your participation.)
- Your post has been deleted. This can have a number of reasons. If you posted an *answer*, it might be deleted because of the *question* being deleted. Or maybe your question or answer was deleted because of the policy here (you posted a link only answer, a low quality question, etc.)

If you still think all these things don't apply to your case, it is best you contact the SE team. Those people has access to moderation tools and even the SE database. You can contact them by clicking the [`Contact Us`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link on the bottom of this page.

Comment: I see my mistake - I should have posted this question on Meta StackOverflow.

Comment: Should I delete this question here? Or ask a moderator to do that?

Comment: Why delete it? It might be useful for future readers.

Comment: Only because it belongs (I believe) in MSO not MSE

Comment: Why? The question is valid cross-site. There will be more users confused.