# What's the difference between meta.stackexchange and meta.stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, mso-mse-split

What's the difference between [meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

[Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) didn't help me out.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags says:

> Questions specific to stackoverflow.com should now be asked on meta.stackoverflow.com

If the reason for using the latter is that the questions deal with stackoverflow only, then why do a **lot** of the questions there *not* deal with anything programm-wise there (for examples, see [active posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/active)), and none of it gets closed (for example [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))?

I also find it confusing that when I search for questions about "comment" on *`meta.stackoverflow.com`* (like [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+comments)), the opened links (mostly) resolve to *`meta.stackexchange.com`*. Yet this isn't really part of the question here, I just stumbled across it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange

Comment: AFAIK, all Metas get the occasional question that **could** be more broadly applicable to the entire network... that doesn't mean that they can't be asked there, to see what that specific site decides. Each site is allowed to set their own policies within the framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchange is the site for the questions about the whole [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), [since The Great Split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014). *Before* it was SE 1.0 site for some purposes (meta which isn't visited I guess), and then shutdown (i.e. not used at all) and just redirecting to Meta Stack Overflow. MSE is not a per-site meta and being only meta which has reputation system (per-site metas derive the rep from their main sites).

Meta Stack Overflow, [since the great split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014), is the site to ask about Stack Overflow (i.e. it's *per-site meta*, like any other metas except this site, MSE) and about Careers Stack Overflow (before the meta for Careers was Meta Stack Exchange, [the change is quite recent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow)). *Before* the split the Meta Stack Overflow wasn't per-site meta and was conveying the questions about all the Stack Exchange network (and also had the independent reputation system), i.e. served the function which is now held by Meta Stack Exchange.

Do note that another interesting thing is that now the Stack Exchange network of sites is often referred as "Stack Overflow company" (e.g. [MSE help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)), and shouldn't be confused with the Stack Overflow itself.

---

> a lot of the questions there not deal with anything programs-wise there

Meta Stack Overflow is needed to discuss Stack Overflow as I mentioned; but this includes discussing scope and meta-problems occurring on SO. (this applies to any meta). Discussing programming problems on MSO is exactly *off*-topic, because not about SO.

As for the redirecting links: this is happening due to that split and the mass question migration from MSE to MSO.