# As of 2017, how exactly does per-site meta work?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

I searched on this site MSE before asking this question. All search results are more than 6 years old (and I found most of them talking about things that's already changed).
In those posts I searched, people said MSO worked as a "service center" but it's clear the present center is MSE. Also I checked my MSO profile and found my rep was derived from Main SO. [This blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) says MSO works as a separate site but obviously it's no longer true.
So how does the way in which per-site metas work different from what it used to be in 2010? What about MSO and MSE?

Please don't mark this question as a duplicate of something *too old*. I'm wondering about what things are **now**, not **before**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference in the way per-site metas work between 2010 and now.

What has changed is that this site used to be called Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow didn't have its own child meta, but now this site is now called Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow *does* have its own child meta.

The change was made for various reasons, not least of which was that Stack Overflow–specific questions were becoming increasingly out of place on a site that was dealing with the entire network.

So, Stack Overflow–specific questions go to Meta Stack Overflow while questions about the wider network come here. This isn't to say that network questions are off topic on child metas. They can be asked there, but they may get better answers here.

Comment: Adding: [Details about that split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014). Also I seem to remember that (unlike the other metas?) MSO had it's own rep and then that was changed to take rep from the main site, maybe that was around split time. It's all fuzzy memories.

Comment: MSE is essentially old MSO