# How can these two users be a member of Meta for longer than the site exists?

Tags: support, meta, users

During some ... research ... I encountered two users here:

- [George Claghorn](/users/128546), member since 2009-06-25
- [Jeff Hardy](/users/129592), member since 2009-06-26

[image]

How can they be a member of Meta Stack Exchange for longer than [Community](/users/-1), [Jeff Atwood](/users/1), [Geoff Dalgas](/users/2) and a bunch of other people (with much lower user numbers) who all joined 2009-06-27? Does it have to do something with the [MSO/MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014) (this site used to be Meta Stack Overflow)?

Comment: Isn't merged accounts normally the reason for time being broken on SE? An early SO/SF account got merged into a MSE one.

Comment: Given the first user's SO join timestamp is identical to the MSE one, that would make sense, but I still have a hard time seeing that happen. I thought you could only merge two accounts on a single site?

Comment: A SEDE query could plot "User# vs AccountAge" and determine whom was *out of order*. Poking around manually I found that there are empty accounts and ones too old for their #. Examples, compare: [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) #1 11 years 4 months, [Mitja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5090/mitja) #5090 11 years 3 months, 
[Matthew Rapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15000/matthew-rapati) #15000 11 years 3 months, ***but*** [User #3000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000) is 404. --- Way back a write error was probably discovered and manually corrected.

Comment: I think the real question here is how could anyone be a member for longer than Jon Skeet?

Comment: @Mureinik Jon Skeet isn't a member of this site, this site is a member of the things Jon Skeet participates in.

Comment: Glorfindel, user [Adam Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis), at 11 years 4 months (# 2915), has been on SO longer than anyone - Jon Skeet, by a month.